# HTML to Display Arabic Order List in Two Columns

Tags: html, css, web, localization

I want to show the a List in Two Columns

**But** I want to show Order List that contains Arabic Language. This means that the direction should be from Right to Left E.g **direction:rtl**. Unfortunately, its not working accurately for me.

```css
ol {
  width: 30em;
}
ol li {
  float: left;
  width: 10em;
}
br {
  clear: left;
}
div.wrapper {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}
```

```html
<h1>List Of Items</h1>
    <div class="wrapper">
    <ol dir="ltr">
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
        <li>Item 3</li>
        <li>Item 4</li>
        <li>Item 5</li>
        <li>Item 6</li>
    </ol>
    <br />
</div>
```

Comment: You mean like this: - https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/QmVymN ?

Comment: did you try replacing the float to 'right'

Comment: @Paulie_D
Sir, I want in such Format.

https://i.imgur.com/rirs4kG.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the required layout

[image]

CSS Columns would work with `rtl` as a direction.

```css
ol {
  width: 30em;
  column-count: 2;
  list-style-position: inside;
}

ol li {
  width: 10em;
}

div.wrapper {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <ol dir="rtl">
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add 'direction: rtl' in 'ol' style:

```css
ol
    {
      direction: rtl;
      width: 30em;
    }
    ol li
    {
      float: left;
      width: 10em;
    }
    br
    {
      clear: left;
    }
    div.wrapper
    {
      margin-bottom: 1em;
    }
```

```html
 <h1>List Of Items</h1>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <ol dir="ltr">
            <li>Item 1</li>
            <li>Item 2</li>
            <li>Item 3</li>
            <li>Item 4</li>
            <li>Item 5</li>
            <li>Item 6</li>
        </ol>
        <br />
    </div>
```

Comment: Sir, I want in such Format.

https://i.imgur.com/rirs4kG.png